# Prefetch count for receiver is less than the max messages requested

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using Azure Service Bus extension for Function App service bus trigger and have below extension settings prefetchCount = 30,

```
 "extensions": {
"serviceBus": {
  "prefetchCount": 30,
  "messageHandlerOptions": {
    "autoComplete": false
  }
}
```

},

All works fine and MAX 30 messages processing also I can see, but I am getting below warning as well,

> [16:29:57 WRN] Prefetch count for receiver with Identifier mytopic/Subscriptions/mytopic-sub1-22876764-e8b7-4d33-86c4-5f98534a369a is less than the max messages requested. When using prefetch, it isn't possible to receive more than the prefetch count in any single Receive call: PrefetchCount: 30; MaxMessages: 1000

What this warning means and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What this warning means and how to get rid of it?

The message tells that the configuration is sub optimal. To fix this, set the prefetch larger than the number of the message you're receiving using a batches recieve.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Feldman. This means I have to set prefetch  >1000 as looks like this is the limit.

Comment: Prefetch ensures there's no lag between requested messages and processing, especially in a high load scenarios. Note that when requesting a batch of messages,  the requested number is likely higher than what the server will provide so setting it to something very high as 1000 is not very effective.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Then can I set it to 0? If I set 0 then how many messages will pick as a batch?

Comment: Setting the prefetch to zero is undesirable. Better leave it at the default then. A batch of 1000 sounds a little off. Don't know the details but I'd reduce the batch and keep the batch smaller. Worth noting the defaults that are very reasonable. I'd work my way from there.

Comment: Ok, to keep batch small we need to set prefetch count? If I set less than 1000 then warning blow up. Or you're suggestion another way to set the batch size?

Comment: The default `maxMessageBatchSize` is 1000. A batch should be under it. If you receive a batch using the trigger, the maximum batch size will be *up-to* 1000. But usually it will be way less than that. My suggestion is to go with the defaults and change those _if_ needed.

Comment: Thanks for all help and info. Appreciate!!!!